# telegram bot python authorize user using user_id

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I declared an array with permitted user id

```
users_id = ['123213213']
```

and trying to validate user

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['authorize'])
def start_command(message):
    if message.from_user.id not in users_id:
        bot.send_message(
            message.chat.id,
            'u are not permitted to run this bot'
        )
    else:
        bot.send_message(
            message.chat.id,
            'u are welcome'
        )
```

I printed `message.from_user.id` and it looks the same as my array object, but i always get message "u are not permitted to run this bot"
please, could somebody explain what am i doing wrong?

Comment: use `print(message.chat.id)` and `print( type(message.chat.id) )` to see what you get in `message.chat.id` - simply learn how to debug code. Maybe you always have ID different then `'123213213`. OR it gives you object different then string - maybe ID is integer and you should use `users_id = [123213213]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`message.chat.id` is integer value so you have to use list with integers

```
users_id = [123213213]
```

---

**BTW:** you can check it with `print()` and `type()`

```
print(message.chat.id, type(message.chat.id))
```